# Flutter: Error when I add a product in firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This error appears when I click on add button in flutter application :

> Stream closed with status: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Firestore in Datastore Mode database projects/share-it-application/databases/(default)., cause=null}.

Code:

```
final GlobalKey<FormState>  _globalkey   = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _store = Store();


 
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                  if(_globalkey.currentState!.validate()){
                    _globalkey.currentState!.save();
                    _store.AddProduct(Product(
                        pName: _name,
                        pPrice: _price,
                        pCategory: _category,
                        pDescrition: _description,
                        pLocation: _image_location)

                    );

                  }
              },
              child: Text(
                'Add Product',
              ),
```

I try to add products in firestore

Comment: When you get an error message you don't understand, it's generally a good idea to do a web search for that first before posting.